# A skipped Sheva Brocha

Tags: halacha, mistakes, sheva-brachos

I was once at a wedding and it came time for Sheva Brochos.

A person was asked to say one of them, say "Sos tosis..." but inadvertently said "Samech t'samech..."

Since there is an order to the Sheva Brochos, what does one do? Can one go back and say the skipped brocha or must one just continue leaving only six to be said?

Comment: user4549, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your interesting question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may wish to [change your username](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/4549) (unless you're attached to the number 4549).

Answer (score 11):

[Klilos Chasanim - page 79](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51005&st=&pgnum=61) in the name of Mesechtas Kallah Rabsi 1:1, Shaalos U'Teshuvos Peer Hador 9, Igros HaRam 23, Tanya Rabsai 91, Beer Haitaiv 62:3, Knesses Hagedola 9:3, Sidur Bais Oved says that if one skipped a Bracha of the Sheva Brachos you just say the skipped Bracha at that point as the order is not Meakaiv.